# Swift - Create list of strings from two array

Tags: arrays, string, list, swift4

I need to compare two arrays containing a list of names and a list of selected indices. I need to get as a result another array with names of just the indices given. How could achieve this? 
I am trying using `foreach` but I get doubled values.

```
let selectedIndices = [1, 3, 7, 10]
let namesArray = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg", "hhh", "jjj", "kkk", "lll", "mmm"] 

finalArray = ["bbb", "ddd", "hhh", "lll"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a quick way todo this using `map` :

```
finalArray = selectedIndices.map{namesArray[$0]}
```

Comment: `finalArray` will not compile.

Answer (score 0):

There is this property of named `indices` that gives you access to each present index of your array. Then you just check if the second array contains the index then return its value. (both examples are indentical, just a matter of preferences. )

```
let filterArray = namesArray.indices.flatMap({ index -> String?  in
    if selectedIndices.contains(index) {
        return namesArray[index]
    }
    return nil 
})
```

or

```
  let filteredArray = namesArray.indices.flatMap({ return  selectedIndices.contains($0) ? namesArray[$0] : nil })

  print(filteredArray) // ["bbb", "ddd", "hhh", "lll"]
```